# Update-database gives an unexpected result - SocketException: such host is unknown

Tags: .net, postgresql, docker, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created an ASP.NET Core application. This application allows you to use a PostgreSQL database through the Entity Framework Core ORM. Everything works fine on the local database. The problems started when I tried to create docker application containers and databases. Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  naladimbot:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}naladimbot
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: NaladimBot/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork  
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 23r2323ffsedsEGDS#%23EAF
      POSTGRES_DB: NaladimBot.Database
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/
    networks:
      - mynetwork

volumes: 
  db: 

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

And this is my connection string in the file appsettings.json :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=db;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=23r2323ffsedsEGDS#%23EAF;Database=NaladimBot.Database;"
}
```

The problem is this: when I build my application in docker-compose mode, everything works fine. Docker Desktop introduces application containers and databases.

[image]

But when I try to apply the migration using the `update-database` command in the Package Manager Console, I get the following response:

```
PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.21 initialized 'NaladimBotContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:6.0.8+e68dfe8b5cbe4a26d20acc36def6187aa1cfdda3' with options: None
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): Such host is unknown.
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, ValueStopwatch stopwatch)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress, AddressFamily family)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|195_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.UnpooledConnectorSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Such host is unknown.
```

What could be the problem?
Please note that when working with a local database (not a database in a container), I do not encounter this problem.

Comment: the hostname `db` is only known to docker containers, if you want to do it from the host (package manager console!) you can access it with localhost.

Comment: @Eldar Then what is the right thing to do in my case? What do you advise?

Comment: You can specify connection string like this :`update-databse -connection "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Username=postgres;Password=23r2323ffsedsEGDS#%23EAF;Database=NaladimBot.Database;"`

Comment: @Eldar Besides `update-database`, what other ways are there to update a database in a Docker container? I tried this - the problem is that if I specify Server=localhost, then the application cannot connect to the database in the container.

Comment: You can check [this](https://medium.com/geekculture/ways-to-run-entity-framework-migrations-in-asp-net-core-6-37719993ddcb) out.